# NPM Failed to Install Error on React Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am getting started with react so trying to build on different examples. My application was working fine but then I tried to start the server [npm start] and received the below error. I'm not sure what I have changed though obviously I have broken something. Any guidance on what is causing this?

[image]

**src/index.js**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'

import Main from 'main'
import * as serviceWorker from 'serviceWorker'
import configureStore from 'configureStore'

import 'typeface-ibm-plex-sans'
import 'styles'

const history = createHashHistory()

const initialState = window.initialReduxState
const store = configureStore(history, initialState)

ReactDOM.render(<Main store={store} history={history} />, document.getElementById('root'))

serviceWorker.unregister()
```

**src/configureStore.ts**

```
import { Store, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { History } from 'history'

import { ApplicationState, rootReducer, rootSaga } from 'store'

export default function configureStore(
  history: History,
  initialState: ApplicationState
): Store<ApplicationState> {
  // create the composing function for our middlewares
  const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({})
  // create the redux-saga middleware
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

  const store = createStore(
    connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), sagaMiddleware))
  )

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  return store
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib":["es2015", "es2016","dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
  }
}
```

**Debug Log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'configureStore',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose npm-session 0accc0570fa2177a
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/configureStore 1116ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for configureStore@latest 404 Not Found: configureStore@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: configureStore@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
9 verbose stack From previous event:
9 verbose stack     at regFetch (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:36:6)
9 verbose stack     at fetchPackument (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/manifest.js:81:10)
9 verbose stack     at getManifest (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/manifest.js:37:10)
9 verbose stack     at manifest (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/manifest.js:24:10)
9 verbose stack     at Object.manifest (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/index.js:12:12)
9 verbose stack     at Object.Fetcher#manifest [as manifest] (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/protoduck/node_modules/genfun/lib/genfun.js:15:38)
9 verbose stack     at manifest (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetch.js:16:18)
9 verbose stack     at pinflight (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/manifest.js:24:12)
9 verbose stack     at /home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:29:24
9 verbose stack From previous event:
9 verbose stack     at _inflight (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:28:25)
9 verbose stack     at /home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:22:14
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
9 verbose stack From previous event:
9 verbose stack     at inflight (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:14:40)
9 verbose stack     at Object.manifest (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/manifest.js:22:10)
9 verbose stack     at fetchPackageMetadata (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:58:10)
9 verbose stack     at limited (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/call-limit/call-limit.js:29:10)
9 verbose stack     at fs.stat (/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:219:20)9 verbose stack     at /home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:284:29
9 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
10 verbose cwd /mnt/c/Users/micha/github/infornite-web-ui
11 verbose Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
12 verbose argv "/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node" "/home/n4nite/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm" "install" "configureStore" "--save"
13 verbose node v8.11.3
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code E404
16 error 404 Not Found: configureStore@latest
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "infornite-web-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.5",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.5",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.30",
    "@types/redux-form": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^9.2.0",
    "class-names": "^1.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.3.0",
    "create-react-app-parcel-typescript": "0.0.5",
    "dotenv-expand": "^4.2.0",
    "emotion": "^9.2.3",
    "emotion-theming": "^9.2.3",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "main": "^1.0.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "polished": "^1.9.3",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-emotion": "^9.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "^4.3.4",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "routes": "^2.1.0",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "styles": "^0.2.1",
    "typeface-ibm-plex-mono": "^0.0.56",
    "typeface-ibm-plex-sans": "^0.0.58",
    "typesafe-actions": "^2.0.4",
    "utils": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-parcel start",
    "build": "react-scripts-parcel build",
    "test": "react-scripts-parcel test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-parcel eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">1%",
      "Firefox ESR",
      "not ie <= 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.3.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.15",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "tslint-config-blvd": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: is `configureStore` set as a dependency in you package.json?

Comment: Show us your `package.json` file - also it's generally a good idea to only import local modules using relative imports (eg. `import configureStore from './configureStore'` - note the `./` to explicitly state "relative to this folder") to be explicit that you aren't trying to import an npm package.

Comment: added package.json

Comment: My suggestion would be to update your import to use relative paths (`'./configureStore'`), delete your package.lock.json, shut down your code editor and then try running `npm install` again.

Comment: I think it might be related to the "baseUrl": "./src", entry in the tsconfig.json file. That was included in a tutorial I went through online to make relative paths easier to deal with but I think it may be causing some problems.

Comment: Try changing the baseUrl to `"baseUrl": "."` in tsconfig.json

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I changed to "baseUrl": "." which gave me errors all over the project but after explicitly changing the path for all of the import statements its now back working again. Its strange that it was working fine a few hours ago but obviously I inadvertently changed something and made a mess of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this. I was using an option in my tsconfig.json file to set the base url to "./src". The intention is that I could use paths relative to the src directory in my import statements rather than full paths so something like

[import something from '../../../my-module']

would just become

[import something from 'my-module']

This worked fine but all of a sudden I started to receive error messages. I assume that I either installed some dependency that didn't support this configuration for relative paths (unlikely) or that I inadvertently made some change that broke this logic without realising I had done it (more likely).

The fix was to change the base url from  "baseUrl": "./src" to  "baseUrl": "." as suggested by @rshepp. When that was done I had to go back and change every import statement that was using relative paths to use full paths. That was a pain but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/configureStore

Indeed `configureStore` is not available on NPM proper : https://www.npmjs.com/package/configureStore gives a "not found" error (compare to e.g. react https://www.npmjs.com/package/react)

## Fix

Either the package.json is wrong (unlikely) OR you are supposed to you registry local to your organization. Use the `--registry` flag in npm and ask your team mates.

Comment: configureStore is a local module and I have included it in the original post.What I want to understand is why NPM is trying to install it when it wasn't doing this before

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't have an organisation. Its just a simple starter project that I am using to learn React. Everything worked fine a couple of hours ago but I inadvertently changed something in the setup that is causing this error now.